# Remove all same characters in list

Tags: python, sorting, set

I want to know how to remove all repeated characters in this list below (not use set()).  I tried to use `remove()` in list but it just can remove first occurence of value.

Ex: input = [23,42,65,73,5,2,73,51]
output = [23,42,65,5,2,51]

```
def number_repeated(lst):
    index = int(input('Remove index : '))
    a = 0
    for num in lst:
        if num == index:
            a += 1
    print('The number of digits are repeated: {}'.format(a))
    list(set(lst)).remove(index)
    return lst

print(number_repeated([23, 42, 65, 73, 5, 2, 73, 51]))
```

Output:

```
[65, 2, 5, 42, 51, 23]
```

Also, why in this code above when I use `set()` is the output not sorted?

Comment: Sets aren't (necessarily) sorted.

Comment: Sets are unordered data structures. If you want to sort, use `sorted(set())` functions.

Comment: That did **not** produce that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def myFunc(lst):    
    list2 = []

    for x in lst:
        if not x in list2:
            list2.append(x)

    list2 = sorted(list2)
    return list2

print(myFunc([23,42,65,73,5,2,73,51]))
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, 23, 42, 51, 65, 73]
```

Comment: I fixed that bug

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to remove all the duplicates:

Example:

```
from collections import Counter

originalList = [23,42,65,73,5,2,73,51]

filteredList = [k for k, v in Counter(originalList).items() if v == 1]

print(filteredList)
```

Comment: thanks you for the answer but i want to define a function not use module :)))